# Local Django server unresponsive when adding function scheduling

Tags: python, django, scheduled-tasks, schedule

I am trying to schedule a function to run everyday using the [Schedule](https://github.com/dbader/schedule)
library.

My local Django server however hangs and becomes unresponsive during the system check after saving the schedules to my code. It is only when I remove the schedule code the system check passes and the server runs without problem.

I have copied the example directly from the documentation and the server is not returning any errors so I am unsure what the problem is ..

views.py

```
.... 

def test_task():
    user = user.objects.get(pk=1)
    user.task_complete = True
    user.save()

schedule.every(10).minutes.do(test_task)

while True:
    schedule.run_pending()
    time.sleep(1)

....
```

Terminal output (hangs here)

```
chaudim@TD app_one % python3 manage.py runserver
Watching for file changes with StatReloader
Performing system checks...
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Django loads (imports) files based on its settings.

When you put this `while` loop in a global scope, it is executed on import. It runs the while loop until it's done. And it's never done. You can add a `print` statement there if you want to see for yourself if that's the root cause.

Normally people use `periodic_tasks` from `celery` but it might be an overkill for your needs.

I'd rather advise to create a [`command`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/howto/custom-management-commands/) so you could run `python manage.py test_task` and on the os level just add a cron job that will run this command every 10 minutes.

Comment: Thanks I manually raised an exception in the while loop to confirm this. Is there a workaround if want to continue using this library?

Comment: Not to my knowledge, no. You might find some other solutions but they have major caveats. There are literally just two options that make sense, cron and celery.